# Suppose that $A_{m\times n}x=0$ has a nontrivial solution $x$. Prove that, for some row vector $z$, the equation $yA=z$ has no solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I believe I'm close to proving this and am just missing a simple observation.

By assumption, dim(NS($A$))$\geq1$. So by the rank-nullity theorem, the dim(CS($A$))$<n$, and hence dim(RS($A$))$<n$ (I know this is a corollary of the RN theorem, not a direct consequence, but I've already proved this). Also, $yA=z$ has a solution $y$ if and only if $z\in$ RS($A$) (again, already proved). So, somehow, I need to conclude that because the dimension of the row space of $A$ is strictly less than the number of columns in $A$, then we can find a row vector that is not a linear combination of the rows of $A$.

Comment: Consider the equation $A^\top y = z^\top$.

Comment: *Hint.* Consider $yAx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume for contradiction that $yA=z$ has a solution $y$ for all vectors $z$. Now, multiply on the right by $x$. This gives, $yAx=zx\Rightarrow y(0)=zx\Rightarrow zx=0$. Then, since $x$ is not the zero vector, $z$ must be orthogonal to $x$. This is a contradiction because we assumed that a solution exists for $\textit{all}$ vectors $z$.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, specifically, $yA=x^T$ has no solution.  (Here $y$ is a row vector and $x$ is a column vector, so $x^T$ is a row vector.)

**Proof**.  If $yA=x^T$ then
$$yAx=x^Tx$$
so
$$y0=\|x\|^2\ ,$$
so $\|x\|^2=0$; but this is not true since $x\ne0$.

**Comment**.  As pointed out, this only works if the scalars are real.  For the complex case, use ${\overline x}^T$ instead of $x^T$.

Comment: +1 for the clever choice of $z$, but we should remark that this answer is not valid when the ground field isn't real.

Answer (score 0):

Another way: The equation $yA = z$ is equivalent to the equation $A^ty^t = z^t$, where $t$ means transpose.

If you choose bases for $V = \mathbb R^n$ and $W = \mathbb R^m$, then $A$ corresponds to a linear transformation $\phi: V \rightarrow W$.  The bases for $V$ and $W$ give you dual bases for the dual vector spaces $V^{\ast}$ and $W^{\ast}$, and $A^t$ corresponds to the dual transformation $\phi^{\ast}: W^{\ast} \rightarrow V^{\ast}$ given by $\phi^{\ast}(f) = f \circ \phi$.

To say that $Ax = 0$ has a nontrivial solution is to say that the kernel of $\phi$ is nonzero.  To say that for some $A^ty = z$ has no solution $y$ is to say that $\phi^{\ast}$ is not surjective.

So the problem becomes to show that if $\phi^{\ast}$ is surjective, then $\phi$ is injective.  This follows from two easyish lemmas:

**Lemma 1**: if $\psi: E \rightarrow F$ is surjective linear transformation, then the dual map $\psi^{\ast}: F ^{\ast} \rightarrow E^{\ast}$ is injective.

Proof: Let $f \in F^{\ast}$, and suppose $\psi^{\ast}(f) = 0$.  Then $f \circ \psi(v) = 0$ for all $v \in E$.  Since $\psi$ is surjective, this means that $f(v) = 0$ for all $v \in F$, i.e. $f$ is the zero element of $F^{\ast}$.

**Lemma 2**: The natural map $V \rightarrow V^{\ast \ast}$ which sends $v \in V$ to the element of $V^{\ast \ast}$ which sends any $f \in V^{\ast}$ to $f(v)$ is an isomorphism, and the diagram

$$\begin{array} V V& \xrightarrow{\phi} & W \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ V^{\ast \ast} & \xrightarrow{\phi^{ \ast \ast}} & W^{\ast \ast } \end{array}$$

is commutative.  Hence $\phi$ is injective/surjective if and only if $\phi^{\ast \ast}$ is.

Proof: boring.

Now we need to show that if $\phi^{\ast}$ is surjective, then $\phi$ is injective.  By Lemma 1 (taking $E = W^{\ast}, F = V^{\ast}$, and $\psi = \phi^{\ast}$), $\phi^{\ast \ast}$ is injective.  By Lemma 2, so is $\phi$, done.